# Mashme.TV chrome extension unable to locate and remove

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

While removing a website from sending me Desktop Notifications I noted I had a this "Mashme.TV" Notification enforced too which apparently was tied to a Chrome Extension I had installed:

[Mashme.TV Chrome Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df5Y4.png)

After checking the Extensions I realized I have nothing that ties to this extension. 
Mashme.io (which is Mashme.TV) seems to only have 1 Extension called "Syncrtc Extension" which I do not have. Moreso, I went to `C:\Users\sameo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` and removed anything that did not have the same ID as the actual Chrome extensions I do own. Now I have 8 folders in that Extension folder and 8 Extensions in my Chrome Extensions menu. I'm out of options.

[Chrome Extension menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0g1h.png)

Kindly ask your help in removing it. I've currently Blocked all permissions it had however I want it completely removed. What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To reinitialize Chrome to a clean state:

- Export all bookmarks
- Uninstall Chrome
- Scrub all Chrome folders
- Install the latest version of Chrome
- Import bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Use AdwCleaner, it's free, and works for most if not all fishy Chrome extensions.